# Upgrading from CouchDB 1.2.x and separating views

Tags: couchdb

We are in the process of upgrading from 1.2.x to 1.5.1 and would like to take advantage of the fact that you can now store databases and views in separate locations. Everything I've read so far indicates all you have to do is set the view_index_dir property.  However since we are upgrading from a time before this feature was available I'm worried this wont work because when I look at our current data directory I only see one file per database.  To put it simply, will it be possible for us to relocate our views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your current data directory, you should have a data base file named

```
<databasename>.couch
```

and a view folder folder named

```
.<databasename>_design
```

per data base.

For migration, just stop the data base, move the view folders to the new location, configure the new location in the *local.ini* (property *view_index_dir*) and restart the data base.

Comment: They're hidden, that was what I was missing! Thanks so much.